# Concatenate path with filename in C

Tags: c

I have the following code, but I need to concatenate the path with the filename in order to create  the fullpath. I´m new in C and I only heard about the sprintf function. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
typedef enum{
    KeyFileRes_NewKeyFound,
    KeyFileRes_NoKeyFound
}   eKeyFileRes;

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct
{
    char Key[50];
    int KeyLen;
} KeyStorage;

#pragma pack(pop)

eKeyFileRes GetNewKeyFile(char *path, UINT64 filename, KeyStorage keyStorage)
{
     char *Fullpath;

     FILE* file = fopen(Fullpath, "r");

     if(file == NULL) {
         return KeyFileRes_NoKeyFound;
     }   
     else { 
         char c;
         while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
             keyStorage.Key[c];
         } 
         keyStorage.KeyLen = sizeof(keyStorage.Key);
      }
      return KeyFileRes_NewKeyFound;
}
```

Comment: You don't close the file and why packing the `struct`? Then: don't use homebrew types/names if there are standard types available. And where do you return the key? C is **strictly** pass-by-value!

Comment: `sprintf` is a good place to start.  Now what have you tried? And why hasn't it worked?

Answer (score 1):

```
char sbuf[1024];
sprintf (sbuf, "%s/%s", pathName, fileName);
```

Comment: use `string.h` and function `strcat()` to concate two strings (character array here ) that can help you make things easier

Comment: @VenuKantSahu - but, I'd rather have 2 '/' characters than none at all

Answer (score 0):

use `string.h` and function `strcat()` to concate two strings (character array here ) that can help you make things easier